# KineticJS canvas on top of Google Map. Shapes fall apart on drag and zoom

Tags: google-maps-api-3, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to display property boundaries on top of a Google Map by using KineticJS and a Google Maps OverviewLayer.

It works great (1000 parcels being shown at a time. Much faster than Google.Maps.Polygon())

When I drag the Google Map down, then zoom in/out, the top shapes get cut off and don't re-draw when I zoom back out.

I'm guessing its a setX, setY thing but I don't understand the underlying concepts enough.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my app:
[KineticJS and Google Maps OverlayView test site](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14878119/map/fancycanvas.html)

[image]

I added a light-green background to the KineticJS canvas to see what it happening when you zoom in.

The canvas seems to stay locked in place and the same width/height but when you zoom in I'm guessing the canvas should grow proportionally.

I can't figure out how to do that though....

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Could you give me step-by-step so I can see the failure?  :)

Comment: I zoom in, then drag down, then drag up and the shapes that were at the top of the viewport lose their tops. I was using a VMware virtual machine... Maybe its a GPU thing? I'll check it again this evening on a different machine

Comment: Tried it on a regular machine and still the same thing. Could the canvas (or what's drawn on the canvas) possibly get moved when recomputing the lat/lngs to pixel coordinates when the map is dragged? I'm not certain how to test for that...